# How to send asynchronous email in web using spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to send asynchronous email from my controller in web based application in Spring. I used annotation @Async on my method but i am not finding place where I have to use @EnableAsync. As i am using xml based configuration. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `<task:annotation-driven/>` in your xml.

Below is sample config for same

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" />
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5"/>
```

For more information have a look at docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-enable-annotation-support)

Comment: how did you infer that it is indeed synchronous execution? Also the configuration snipped shared is sample, try increasing the `pool-size` to desired value.

Answer (score -3):

Put @enableasync in configuration class.

Comment: `@Enableasync` must be in a `@Configuration` class. Also Op says, That he is using XML based configuration